# What is a better practice than using macros to overload operatiors?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a simple newtype-like class. What is the best, maintainable way to implement operator overloads?

Here's an example function:

```
constexpr auto & operator +=( class_t const & that ) const noexcept
{
    data += that.data;
    return *this;
}
```

Usually what I do to overload all the operators is this:

```
#define operation( op ) \
constexpr auto & operator op( class_t const & that ) noexcept \
{ \
    data op that.data; \
    return *this; \
}
operation( += )
operation( -= )
operation( *= )
operation( /= )
#undef operation
```

This makes it easy to update them if there's a bug or if I forgot something like "noexcept".
The problem is that debugging this is impossible since it's a macro without substituting it. Theoretically, this shouldn't be a problem because it should always work, but that's not always the case.

What's the best practice in this case?

Comment: "the best, maintainable way" is to define them without macros.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Then modifying them is a pain in the ass and the class headers look super cluttered.

Comment: Yuck. Write them out longhand. They might even differ, for example you might want to throw an exception for `/=` if the argument is zero.

Comment: So the consensus is no macros? That stinks but I understand.

Comment: Well, you've just discovered why C++ is the most complicated, hardest, general purpose programming language in use today. There's very little which C++ makes easy for you. You have to do all the work yourself. There are no magic shortcuts in C++.

Comment: I never thought about doing that, that's kinda "smart" but way too overkill. Just write the complete function for each operator.

Comment: I very much like this approach, even though two very experienced C++ contributors here disagree. Perhaps @Bathsheba or Sam would consider writing an answer elaborating on their objections? The reason I *like* it are exactly maintainability and the reduced possibility of typos. (Because like with all boilerplate code, the longhand versions will probably be produced by copy/paste with manual changes of the respective relevant parts, which is error prone. It's a typical mistake to miss one place to change in one of the overloads, and reviewing such boilerplate code is tedious but hard.)

Answer (score 0):

Boost.Operators offers some way to mitigate this issue, though not in the way you are trying to do above. Still, it can reduce the clutter.

The idea in Boost.Operators is that you can define as a parent class various groups of operations that imply each other. Say if you have `operator+=`, you will get `operator+` for free. You still have to spell out the basic operators, but after that it Boost can provide you with the missing set.